# Unity video player crash on whatsapp notifications

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, video

I'm developing an android app from Unity where the user can see two 360 tours about wildlife.
Everything works fine while the phone doesn't receive notifications but for example when a Whatsapp notification appears while a video is playing it crashes (video player goes black) and the sound keeps playing.

Anyone knows what is happening? o.o

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  This has nothing to do with coding. Off topic since no code has been posted that would demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't attach code because I really don't know what is happening.
If it helps I tried to use OnApplicationFocus and OnApplicationPause but this events aren't solved the problem.